# How to know if audio ended in React js with toggle button

Tags: reactjs

I have built a toggle button that turns on & off the audio, but my problem is how can I return the toggle button to off when the audio has finished and it's building with react js if you can help me with some hints.

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import './playSong.css';
Import music from './THREE.mp3';

const PlaySong = () => {
const [activeSong, setActiveSong] = useState(false);
var [saveSong, setSaveSong] = useState({});

var drake = {
    value: 3,
    name: 'Energy',
    artist: 'Drake',
    audio: music, //
};

function handlePlayPause() {
    let states = !activeSong;
    setActiveSong(states);

    if (states) {  
        playSong(drake); // load song and play it
    }
    else {
        togglePause(saveSong); // pause song
    }

}

function playSong(drake) {
    var Song = new Audio(drake.audio);
    Song.play();
    setSaveSong(Song);
    return Song;
}

function togglePause(saveSong) {
    saveSong.pause();
    setSaveSong({});
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="button r" id="button-4">    
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" onChange={handlePlayPause} checked= 
            {activeSong} />
            <div className="knobs" />
            <div className="layer" />
        </div>
    </div>
   )
  }

 export default PlaySong
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used an audio element and mixed it with my toggle button & it's working.

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
import './playSong.css';
import music from './THREE.mp3';

const PlaySong = () => {
const [activeSong, setActiveSong] = useState(false);
var [saveSong, setSaveSong] = useState({});

// var drake = {
//     value: 3,
//     name: 'Energy',
//     artist: 'Drake',
//     audio: music, //
// };

function handlePlayPause() {
    let states = !activeSong;
    setActiveSong(states);

    if (states) {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");  
        playSong(myAudio); // load song and play it
    }
    else {
        togglePause(saveSong); // pause song
    }

}

function playSong(myAudio) {
    if (myAudio) {
        myAudio.play();
        setSaveSong(myAudio);
        return myAudio;
    }
    // var Song = new Audio(drake.audio);
    // Song.play();
    // setSaveSong(Song);
    // return Song;
}

function togglePause(saveSong) {
    if (saveSong) {
        saveSong.pause();
        setSaveSong({});
    }
}

function handleEnded() {
    setActiveSong(false);
    setSaveSong({});
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="button r" id="button-4">    
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" onChange= 
            {handlePlayPause} checked={activeSong} />
            <div className="knobs" />
            <div className="layer" />
        </div>
        <audio id="myAudio" onEnded={handleEnded}>
            <source src={music} type="audio/mpeg" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>
)
}

export default PlaySong
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running all of your audio code through `<audio>` tag?

It has many events which you can supply handlers for.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Specifically the `ended` or `onended` (maybe `onEnded`) event is the one you may want to look at.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Comment: Now if I used <audio> I have to remove all my code and style I don't want that.

Comment: You can probably access the same events from a an Audio obj if that's what you're using. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio

Comment: Audio Tags also come with their own controls so you might not need to make your own button.

Comment: I work with your advice mixed with my toggle & it's work I will show you.